# How to get Reactor Core's Flux caching to work

Tags: java, caching, asynchronous, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a problem understanding how reactor core's caching of Fluxes is meant to work.

However, maybe the answer to this question might be trivial or my example code is downright idiotic, but how caching works with Flux is nowhere shown in a code example/blog/tutorial after my research. May be anyone can help me to get it running, so that other people also have a functional Flux caching example as a boiler plate.

So, I have following code:

```
// The source with cache:
Flux<Instant> values
    = Flux
        .generate((SynchronousSink<Instant> it) -> {
                    it.next(Instant.now());
                    waitingForMillis(50);
        })
        .take(5)
        .cache(Duration.ofMillis(500)); // 500ms per item


// 1st time:
System.out.println("Printing data the 1st time, then the cache should be filled:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);

System.out.printf("%nWaiting ...%n");
waitingForMillis(1000);

// 2nd time:
System.out.println("Printing data the 2nd time, still the data from the cache should be printed:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);

System.out.printf("%nWaiting ...%n");
waitingForMillis(30_000);

// 3rd time:
System.out.println("Printing data the 3rd time, now, new data should be printed (be generated), because the cache timed out:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The scenario I have in mind:

Virtually, I think that the cached Flux values will provide its subscribers with the cached values the 1st time and the 2nd time. - For the 3rd time, after 30000ms have elapsed, I think, that values will provide new values to subscribers, because the cache timed out.

What actually happens after my interpretation:

The cache never times out and always the initial values are provided to following subscriber.

Question (yes, multiple questions):

What have I done wrong? What thinking/interpretation error is in that example? How can I get this code running to fulfill the caching after the scenario I had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works as you intended. I changed the internal waiting in the generator function to use the `delayElements` method and extended the cache time. (It's not per element, it is the lifetime of each element.) I tested the `cache` and the `take` both ways and either way works fine.

```
Flux<Instant> values =
Flux.generate(
    (SynchronousSink<Instant> it) -> {
        it.next(Instant.now());
    })
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(50))
    .cache(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
    .take(5);

// 1st time:
System.out.println("Printing data the 1st time, then the cache should be filled:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);

System.out.printf("%nWaiting ...%n");
waitingForMillis(1000);

// 2nd time:
System.out.println(
    "Printing data the 2nd time, still the data from the cache should be printed:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);

System.out.printf("%nWaiting ...%n");
waitingForMillis(30_000);

// 3rd time:
System.out.println(
    "Printing data the 3rd time, now, new data should be printed (be generated), because the cache timed out:");
values.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output of the above was:

```
Printing data the 1st time, then the cache should be filled:

Waiting ...
2018-05-07T10:03:16.316Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.412Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.465Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.517Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.569Z
Printing data the 2nd time, still the data from the cache should be printed:
2018-05-07T10:03:16.316Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.412Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.465Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.517Z
2018-05-07T10:03:16.569Z

Waiting ...
Printing data the 3rd time, now, new data should be printed (be generated), because the cache timed out:
2018-05-07T10:03:47.352Z
2018-05-07T10:03:47.403Z
2018-05-07T10:03:47.458Z
2018-05-07T10:03:47.511Z
2018-05-07T10:03:47.565Z
```